# assignment operator doesnt work

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a constructor to represent big numbers and store them into a vector:
my class is composed of a vector, a boolean and an int and is supposed to represent big numbers.

```
    CBigInt(const char* str2)
{
    string str=string(str2);
    num.resize(200000);
    if (str[0]=='-') 
    {
        signe=true; 
        pos=str.length()-1;
        for (int i=pos;i>0;i--)
        {
            num[pos-i]=str[i]-48;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        signe=false; 
        pos=str.length();
        for (int i=pos;i>=0;i--)
        {
            num[pos-i-1]=str[i]-48;
        }
    }       
}
```

and I get an error: http://pastebin.com/cy82XaLF

Comment: string is `std::string`?

Comment: yes string is std::string.

Comment: Well you could do `CbigInt foo = std::string("11113")` but Im still wondering why it cant implicitely construct the string from `const char[]`

Comment: Btw, you might want to define a `user-defined literal` if you have c++11 support

Comment: because `const char[]` is not std::string?

Comment: @Deduplicator Ever heard of implicit construction? Guess why you can pass a string literal to a function taking a `std::string` even if a string literal has `const char[]` as type?

Comment: Tip: Avoid magic numbers, use character literals instead. That is far less confusing. `'0'`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can use the operator = to define a CBigInt from an integer or another CBigInt. What would user-defined literial change here? I am  a beginner.

Comment: user-defined literals are a feature introduced in c++11, allowing you to write e.g `100B` yielding a `CBigInt`. This is however not related to your problem, I just mentioned it as a little addition

Comment: @Paranaix User-defined literal suffixes that do not start with `_` are reserved.

Answer (score 3):

A conversion sequence can only contain at most one implicit user-defined conversion. Yours contains two: `const char[]` to `string`, then `string` to `CBigInt`.

A simple fix is to make one conversion explicit:

```
CBigInt autre("123456789012345678901111");
```

Comment: or using const char * directly might be better?

Answer (score 3):

Declare and implement an additional constructor on top of the one that you already have:

```
CBigInt::CBigInt(const char* str):CBigInt(string(str)){}
```

Comment: But isn't it going to make a confusion between the two constructors?

Comment: @stepanBY: 1. You should **update** your question rather than changing it, because now non of the answers previously given seem relevant. 2. For the current problem, you need to provide the code that is actually causing the runtime error (and not just the `CBigInt` class).

Answer (score 0):

Probabily they doesn't work because the compile do not provide two implicit convertion at same operation, one from `Const Char*` to `String`, and `String` to `CBigInt`. And only when the type was a `CBigInt` is possible call `operator =`.

This could be repare at this peace of code that compile correctily with your class:

```
   CBigInt a("99") //justo one implicit convertion, to const char * to string
   string std;
   a = std; //just one implicit convertion, to String to CBigInt
   a = string("99"); //just one implicit convertion, to String to CBigInt
```

My sugestion is copy your code from `CBigInt(string)` to `CBigInt(const char*)` and adpatad to looking for '\0' at the end of string.

Another suggestion that I have to you is exchange your signature from `CBigInt(string)` to `CBigInt(const string&)`, it's faster because doesn't copy the string and no code have to be changed.

Comment: But after that, will I have to adapt all the operator I have overloaded? by replacing const string by const *char?